# swift pan a imageView that is behind a view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiimage

Is it possible to pan an object that is behind another object?
Currently I have a imageview and a view with clear color and only a border around, that I can see the imageview. I want to achieve that the view with the border is always on top. Trough the view I want to pan the image view with pan gesture.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Pan gesture to the view and apply the transformation to the imageView.

```
var translation = panGesture.translationInView(imageView)
panGesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: imageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `isUserInteractionEnabled` false for upper view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bottomView = UIView.init(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
        bottomView.backgroundColor = .yellow

        let upperView = UIView.init(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
        upperView.backgroundColor = .clear
        upperView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        upperView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        upperView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //<------------

        view.addSubview(bottomView)
        view.addSubview(upperView)

        bottomView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handle)))

    }

    @objc func handle() {
        print("handletapgesture")
    }
}
```